# How do I add a new field/meta box to the Custom Post Type Portfolio in the Kaboodle Wootheme?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I've created CPTs using Types in the past, and I've built custom templates, but finding the method for adding a field to an existing Woothemes CPT is frustrating.  I'm struggling to find the correct code to either hook or just straight modify the php? Thoughts?

Comment: Don’t they offer docs and/or support?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add meta box using this plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

The UI of this plugin is not confusing and I also personally use it.

Comment: @IoQ - Thanks, sure do appreciate the help. I Installed the plugin but achieved the same results as I achieved with the plugin Types. I can add new Groups and add new Fields to that new Group, but can not access the existing fields or the existing group of fields used to create the Custom Post Type "Portfolio" within the theme.  How can I access and control that existing CPT?

Comment: Im confuse on your question. You mean the codes that create your "Portfolio" post type?

Comment: I'm working this myself as well. So, far, I've found that I can add a custom field to a Woothemes CPT by editing the file theme-options.php and searching for "portfolio" without the quotes. This brings you to an area where you can see a series of $woo_metaboxes[]. I simply added the following lines of code in the order I wanted it to show up under the Woothemes CPT metabox:  (adding code now hold on)

Comment: Sorry IoQ didn't see your question before I posted. Yes, if need be. I'd rather use a plugin for brevity sake, and because I feel a bit thick and lethargic in php files. So I'm clawing my way through it hoping someone else can lend a quicker hand.

Comment: have you checked your functions.php? Usually it is added there or there might be files which are included for post type purposes.

Comment: I can't find a good way to enter code so I'll enter additional comments for each of the five lines. As an asside, I'll take advice on how to do this a better way. Here is what I added:

Comment: $woo_metaboxes[] = array (  "name"  => "my-slug",

Comment: Sorry. Code isn't easy to input. I simply copied an array that I wanted to replicate and pasted the whole 5 lines in the right spot. I changed the slug, label, type and description then updated the file. Checked the success by going to the CPT and entered data into the new field. Clicked update and the data held. I believe that's it. Now I'll work on calling the data in the template to verify that the information is saving to the database and is useable.